# Unable to change properties of CAEmitter SWIFT

Tags: swift, properties, core-animation, swift-playground

I am trying to set up an CAEmitter. All of that works but I want to change the birthRate to zero after one second so the animation stops and no new particles are spawned. Here is the code I currently have:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))

let emitterLayer = CAEmitterLayer()

func degreesToRadians(degrees: Double) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(degrees * M_PI / 180.0)
}

emitterLayer.emitterPosition = CGPoint(x: 320, y: 150)

let cell = CAEmitterCell()
cell.birthRate = 100
cell.lifetime = 1
cell.velocity = 300
cell.scale = 0.1

cell.contents = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Lock copy.png").cgImage

let zeroDegreesInRadians = degreesToRadians(degrees: 0.0)
cell.spin = degreesToRadians(degrees: 130.0)
cell.spinRange = zeroDegreesInRadians
cell.emissionRange = degreesToRadians(degrees: 100)

cell.xAcceleration = -800.0
cell.yAcceleration = 1000.0

emitterLayer.emitterCells = [cell]

let delayTime = DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(1.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: delayTime, execute:{
    cell.birthRate = 0
})

view.layer.addSublayer(emitterLayer)

let page = PlaygroundPage.current
page.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
page.liveView = view
```

I can't see any effect so why does my code not work? Also how would I add a CABasicAnimation to change the properties. CAEmitterCell has no method like `.add(anim: CAAnimation, forKey: String)`. Would it be added to the layer?
Thanks for help.

Comment: What about using a Timer for that? The you could reduce the birthrate by a certain amount each time the timer fires

Comment: And why doesn't my code reduce the birth rate for once?

Comment: Is your code to reduce the birth rate actually being called? The way you initialize `delayTime` seems sketchy.

Comment: It's being called. I can print something out in this block of code. I also hab the same issue when I use a simple timer.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably set emitterLayer's birthRate to zero.

Or, you could also use emitterLayer's lifetime to zero.